# java.net.SocketException: socket closed

Tags: java, android, сокет, клиент-сервер

Здравствуйте программисты. Помогите решить очередную задачу. Второй день копаюсь и не понимаю в чём проблема.

На компьютере запущен сервер на порту 5500. К нему присоединяется клиент, в роли которого - Android приложение. Оно сразу же отправляет запрос серверу. Сервер, после обработки запроса отправляет ответ Android приложению. Но к сожалению, получить ответ не получается: `java.net.SocketException: socket closed`. Внизу части исходного кода, в котором, вероятно, должна быть моя ошибка.

**Исходный код Android приложения:**

1) Класс получения ответа от сервера

```
class SocketManager {

    static Socket i3;
    static Boolean i4 = false;
    static String i5;

    public static String i1(final Properties i1, final String i2) {
        try {
            new Thread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        i3 = new Socket();
                        i3.setSoTimeout(4000);
                        i3.connect(new InetSocketAddress(i1.getProperty("hostIp"), 5500), 4000);
                        String i6 = i1.getProperty("username") + System.lineSeparator() + i1.getProperty("password");
                        if (i2 != null) {
                            i6 += System.lineSeparator() + i2;
                        }
                        BufferedWriter i7 = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(i3.getOutputStream()));
                        i7.write(i6);
                        i7.flush();
                        //=== ВОТ ЭТА СТРОЧКА ВЫЛЕТАЕТ @
                        i5 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(i3.getInputStream())).readLine();
                        //===
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        Log.d("", e1.toString());
                        i5 = null;
                    }
                    i4 = true;
                    return;
                }
            }).start();
            while (!i4) {
            }
            i3 = null;
            return i5;
        } catch (Exception e1) {
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

2) Как с помощью класса `SocketManager` получить ответ сервера:

```
Properties i1 = new Properties();
// Загружаю файл с логином и паролем. Его содержимое:
//      hostIp = мой IP-адрес
//      username = user
//      password = user
i1.load(new FileInputStream("file.properties"));
String i2 = "мой запрос на сервер";
// Получаю и показываю ответ от сервера
Toast.makeText(this, "Ответ сервера следующий:" + System.lineSeparator() + SocketManager.i1(i1, i2), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

**Исходный код сервера на компьютере:**

```
public Void i1() {
    String i1 = "";
    // 'this.i1' это 'myServerSocket.accept()'
    BufferedReader i11 = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.i1.getInputStream()));
    while (true) {
        String i2 = i11.readLine();
        if (i2 == null) {
            break;
        } else {
            i1 += System.lineSeparator() + i2;
        }
    }
    i1 = i1.substring(System.lineSeparator().length(), i1.length());
    System.out.println(i1);
    String[] i2 = i1.split(System.lineSeparator());
    // И тут определяем, что надо приложению
    if (i2[1].equals("команда 1") {
        i2("user".getBytes());
    } else {
        i2("false".getBytes());
    }
    return null;
}

private Void i2(byte[] i1) throws Exception {
    if (this.i1.isConnected() && !this.i1.isClosed()) {
        OutputStream i2 = this.i1.getOutputStream();
        i2.write(i1);
        i2.flush();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: ребят, срочно надо до понедельника..

Comment: Для начала необходимо определиться - сервер закрывает сокет или клиент по таймауту. Сделайте `i3.setSoTimeout(4000);` побольше или вообще ноль. Ещё там с потоками не всё так просто. Посмотрите пример [Android Socket Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/socket-core/android-socket-example/). И никогда больше не называйте так переменные и методы - это ужас какой-то.